# Instagram API in python doesn't work

Tags: python, module, instagram, instagram-api

Installed Anaconda, but it seems that that it doesn't have an Instagram module. I installed python because there was no path directory on my computer and added instagram module manually. Tried to run my program in Anaconda's Spyder and in Python's shell with this code:

from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

```
access_token = "
client_secret = "
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print (media.caption.text)
```

but always get the error (file is called 'main.py')

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'instagram'
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the instagram library from PyPi prior to attempting to import it.

`$ conda install instagram`
 -or-
`$ pip install instagram`

Also, you should not post client secrets and access tokens on the internet. Effectively, those are the same thing as usernames and passwords.

Comment: thank you, forgot about that :| installed pypi instagram, so where should I store it? Sorry for such a question

Comment: I am not sure I track what you are asking. I am not exactly sure how it works with conda, but with `pip`, you don't "store" an installed library, the package manager will do that for you. You merely install the package with the above command and then use the library by `import`ing it.

Comment: I've tried and it gave me this: 
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @AlinaDyussupova are you using Anaconda with conda? You might want to look at the documentation on using the package manager. https://conda.io/docs/using/pkgs.html.

You might also try `pip install instagram` if conda is not installed.